# QR Codes generation from MySQL rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, qr-code

I have a serious problem, maybe to some it's not so serious, but as I am not good with programming, for me it's a really tough problem. I will try to explain all clearly:

I am using **WAMP (MySQL and PHP)**, I have database called ''store'', which includes table with fields:

1.) ID (with Auto Increment)

2.) Name (Varchar)

3.) Description (Varchar)

4.) Image (Blob) - where to store QR code

Basically, I am creating small online store. I have inserted some rows, like Name - Chair, Description - Small chair 2x2 for kitchen

Now, what I want to do is to have a script, as I understand, I need some kind of loop script or etc., which goes through my MySQL database every record and creates of it a QR Code to every row. I would like to include in QR code fields "Name", "Description" and also link to webpage, which my item has got description about current item (say item ''Chair''). I wanted to know, is it possible to do that?

For creating QR codes, I tried to use **PHP QR Code Library** (http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/)

I think it's easy to use, I opened it in my localhost *index.php* page of Library and it opens webpage, where you can enter what you want to put in QR code and then it generates it for you and automatically saves QR code picture in Folder.

So, my question is, guys, how to make script/loop, which goes through every row what I have in MySQL database and creates out of it QR Code? As I understand, I need script which goes through every row of database, then script which creates QR code automatically (including in script that PHP QR Code Library, with who it can create QR codes) and script, which inserts QR codes in Image (Blob) field? Also then I will need another script to display QR code in webpage? Damn, that's a lot..

Before I asked this question, I tried to manually create QR code with PHP QR Code Library and insert it in my Database and then display. I used this tutorial how to do that and it worked: http://installationquery.blogspot.com/2012/05/inserting-and-displaying-images-from.html

Maybe that will help somebody. So, really looking forward for some help here and huge thanks in advance.

Comment: Anybody? Maybe I didn't fully explained question, please let me know.

Comment: You have too loop through every row in your table.. select * from table where Image != NULL.. You can do a check if the item has qr code picture in the loop. If item has no qr code, create it... The script my crash after a while, depending on how many rows you got. You could create a temporary column called has qr code and you set it to 0 or 1 depending if you have created a qr code for the specific row.

Comment: @Medda86 Thanks a ton for reply. What I want to do,is to create QR code to each row and store it in database.Before that I don't have any QR codes in database.I managed to manually create QR codes and insert them in database and then display.I used http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/ to create QR codes.Then I created script,which uploads image to database and inserts it in Blob field and also then created script, which display image by ID.I used this tutorial and code examples there: http://vikasmahajan.wordpress.com/2010/07/07/inserting-and-displaying-images-in-mysql-using-php/

Answer (score 0):

Okej, you can try do something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test_image WHERE image = ''") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo 'Working with id '.$row['id'].' and name '.$row['name'].'<br />';
    // DO YOUR CODE FOR THIS ROW IN YOUR TABLE
}
```

Comment: I tried to put that code in diff php page and open on my localhost, when tried to open it, it showed code, but didn't do anything. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I get nothing, when try to open php with code posted above. It shows code, which is in php, that's all. Take a look at picture, please: http://www4.zippyshare.com/v/82897681/file.html

Comment: have you put it in php tags? Are you connected to your database?

Comment: Yes, I put php tags. Now it shows ''No Database selected'', but I added in php: $host="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$db="veikals";

Comment: Good, so you get the list of rows now? You can add LIMIT 10 like this: WHERE image = ''" LIMIT 10 ... so you can work with 10 rows at a time...

Comment: No, as I said, it now shows, when try to open php with code you posted above, this: "No database selected"

Comment: Well, you need to add the connection just like you did in the other script you got working.